# sharepoint web service does not store data in one column of list

Tags: sharepoint

I try to write some data to a list column using sharepoint web service.  The column is single line of text.  The text I want to write into the column is an xml text.  For example

But sharepoint did not store it; other plain text seems to work.

Do I need to replace xml tags with some code, for example:  > is ">"

I did just that, but still is not working.

What am I doin wrong?

Comment: Could You please share the code that you have tried

Comment: Maybe try to change the '<' with '&lt;' and '>' with '&gt;', also the '&' should be changed to '&amp;'